# Dynamical Homomorphism of monotones over $[0,1]$

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems

Let $f(x):[0, 1]\rightarrow [0, 1]$ be a continuous monotone function satsfying $f(x)>x \forall x\in (0, 1)$. Show that there is a homeomorphism $V: [0, 1]\rightarrow [0, 1]$ such that
$$V(f(x))=\sqrt{V(x)}$$
holds.

THIS IS A HOMEWORK PROBLEM. I have thought about for quite some time tho.

Comment: There is no such $f$. The problem is $f(1)$. Perhaps you mean $f(x)>x$ for $x\in[0,1)$? Or maybe $f(x)\ge x$ for $x\in[0,1]$?

Comment: I meant the open interval. Its edited now

Comment: Have you figured out that $V(1) = 1$, and that $V(0) = 0$? That $V$ is increasing? I appreciate that you are honest that it is a homework problem, but it would help if you include what you've already determined, and what has you stuck.

Comment: What is the context of your homework?

Answer (score 2):

It is not true.

Let $f$ be any function satisfying your requirements and such that $f(0) > 0$. An example is $f(x) = (x+1)/2$. This is a strictly increasing continuous function such that for $x < 1$
$$f(x) > (x+x)/2 = x .$$

Assume that there exists $V$. Then we must have either $V(0) = 0$ or $V(0) = 1$. In both case we see that $\sqrt{V(0)} = V(0)$. But then
$$V(f(0)) = \sqrt{V(0)} = V(0)$$
which implies $f(0) = 0$ because $V$ is a homeomorphism. This is a contradiction.

**Edited:**

Paul Sinclair asked if the results holds if we additionally require $f(0) = 0$. If we use the standard interpretation of "monotonic" (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function), then the answer is again "no". Take any $f$ which is not strictly monotonic. An example is
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
3x & x \le 1/4  \\
3/4 & 1/4 \le x \le 1/2 \\
(x + 1)/2 & x \ge 1/2
\end{cases}$$
This is an increasing continuous function as required. But we have $f(a) = f(b)$ for some points $0 \le a < b \le 1$ and therefore
$$\sqrt{V(a)} = V(f(a) = V(f(b)) = \sqrt{V(b)}$$
which is again a contradiction.

Thus, the question remains open for strictly monotonic $f$ with $f(0) = 0$.

**Edited:**

If $V$ exists, we get $f(x) = V^{-1}\left(\sqrt{V(x)} \right)$. So let us see what can be said about the function $h_V = V^{-1} \circ \sqrt{\phantom {x}} \circ V$ if $V$ is a homeomorphism. Since $\sqrt{\phantom {x}} : [0,1] \to [0,1]$ is a homeomorphism, also $h_V$ is one. Moreover, since $V$ is a homeomorphism we must have either (1) $V(0) = 0, V(1) = 1$ or (2) $V(0) = 1, V(1) = 0$. In both cases we get $h_V(0) = 0, h_V(1) = 1$. Thus $h_V$ is a strictly increasing continuous function.

In case (1) $V$ is strictly increasing and so is $V^{-1}$. Thus for $x \in (0,1)$ we get $h_V(x) = V^{-1}(\sqrt{V(x)}) > V^{-1}(V(x)) = x$ because $\sqrt{y} > y$ for $y \in (0,1)$. Thus necessary conditions for $f = h_V$ are

(a) $f$ is a strictly increasing continuous function,

(b) $f(0) = 0, f(1) = 1$,

(c) $f(x) > x$ for $x \in (0,1)$.

Note that the requirement $f(1) = 1$ is redundant because (c) implies $f(1) = \lim_{x \to 1} f(x) \ge  \lim_{x \to 1} x = 1$.

Similarly, in case (2) we get as necessary conditions

(a) $f$ is a strictly increasing continuous function,

(b) $f(0) = 0, f(1) = 1$,

(c) $f(x) < x$ for $x \in (0,1)$.

Now $f(0) = 0$ is redundant.

Let us finally consider the homeomorphism $V(x) = x^\alpha$ with $\alpha > 0$. We have $V^{-1}(x) = x^{1/\alpha}$ which shows that
$$h_V(x) = \sqrt{x} .$$
Therefore possible solutions $V$ of $f = h_V$ cannot be expected to be unique.

Comment: +1 - this answers the question as asked, but I am wondering if the result would hold with the additional hypothesis that $f(0) = 0$.

Comment: The "open" part was actually my problem. But it's my own fault that i did not state it properly. Thank you guys very much anyway